# Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘JuliaCall’

Tags: julia, quarto, julia-plots

I just started to learn `Julia` in [`Quarto`](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/julia.html) but when I run the following code in a Julia chunk in Quarto:

````
---
title: "Julia in Quarto"
editor: visual
format: html
---

```{julia}
# generating vectors
# x-axis
x = 1:10
 
# y-axis
y = rand(10)
 
# simple plotting
plot(x, y)
```
````

It returns:

```
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘JuliaCall’
```

The error still appears even when adding:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("JuliaCall")
```

To the code chunk. Does anyone knows how to run the following Julia code in Quarto?

---

Please note: I use Rstudio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JuliaCall` is an R package. Quarto executes Julia code using the [`IJulia`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) Jupyter kernel. To use it, specify `jupyter: julia_version` in the YAML header. A [Quarto installation guide](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/julia.html#installation) is available.

To render Quarto documents that contain julia chunks

1. start julia
2. Enter package mode by pressing `]`.
3. run `Add IJulia`
4. Go back to the REPL (backspace), the default prompt after you start julia
5. run `using IJulia`
6. run `notebook()`. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or quitting julia to stop the Jupyter kernel.

If you don't have Jupyter installed at this point, this will be installed, refer to the above guide for details. This may take a while and prompt some input.

Now you should be able to render a document via the [Quarto Cli](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli) from a shell and<sup>1</sup> RStudio. For example, the following *example.qmd* should render and print a matrix.

````
---
title: "Bla"
jupyter: julia-1.8
---
```{julia}
[1 2 3]
```
````

This may a slow. Refer to the above guide on installing `Revise.jl` and using Jupyter Cache to speed things up. I personally experience speedup in using VSCode + Quarto extension over RStudio.

---

If not, the following allows R users to run julia code from within R and RStudio,

1. in R, use `install.package("JuliaCall")`
2. in R, run `JuliaCall::julia_setup()`

This takes care of some PATH variable and comes with the `installJulia` optional argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer! To only thing I did different was running `import Pkg;Pkg.add("IJulia")` in Julia mode. The rest worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Quinten same outcome with different syntax, however, note that `using` - `import` is part of an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/39235) likely to change in Julia 2.0